# ¿Por qué "martillo" es "Cruz de la Orden de San Juan, quitado el brazo derecho"?

Tags: etimología, historia, religión

La tercera acepción de [**martillo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OVFrDJP) es:

> 3. m. Cruz de la Orden de San Juan, quitado el brazo derecho.

Esta acepción, según el [NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle), aparece ya en la edición de 1803 del Diccionario de la Lengua, como

> La cruz de la religión de San Juan, quitado el brazo derecho.

Según [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_de_Malta), la **Orden de San Juan** es la **Orden de Malta**, y su cruz, de nuevo según [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruz_de_Malta), tiene este aspecto:

[image]

Pero no acabo de ver la relación entre una **cruz** y el martillo, por qué la relación es precisamente con la de la **Orden de San Juan** y no con otra cruz, y por qué hay que quitar precisamente **el brazo derecho** de la cruz (y no el izquierdo).

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta corresponde más a la historia de los símbolos que al idioma español. De todas formas es muy interesante. No he podido encontrar ni un solo dato al respecto. :(

Comment: @pablodf76 [he preguntado](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/50186/35870) en el sitio de Historia, partiendo de los pocos datos que he encontrado, a ver si ellos pueden profundizar un poco más y así amplío mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando pasan este tipo de cosas, en mi opinión el mejor sitio donde buscar es en el [Fichero General](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html) de la RAE, que contiene cientos de fichas que ayudan a entender el porqué de muchas acepciones del diccionario. Lo malo es que para *martillo* hay más de 500 fichas, lo que obliga a buscar con paciencia.

De momento he encontrado una que aporta un poquito más de información:

> MARTILLO. s. m. La cruz de la orden de San Juan de Malta, quitado el brazo derecho, que es como la deben usar los hermanos sirvientes.

Bueno, algo es algo. La Orden tenía tres clases de miembros: los caballeros, los religiosos y los sirvientes. Estos últimos podían ser sirvientes de los caballeros o sirvientes de los capellanes. La cita anterior aparece en el *Diccionario militar español-francés* de Federico Moretti, publicado en 1828. En [este diccionario](https://books.google.es/books?id=c1CEPbC4l9kC&pg=PA252&source=bl&q=malta&f=false#v=snippet&q=malta&f=false), en la entrada sobre la propia orden de San Juan de Malta (página 247) dice:

> La divisa actual de los primeros [los caballeros] es una cruz de oro de ocho puntas, coronada y esmaltada de blanco, angulada de lises de oro, que llevan al ojal de la casaca, pendiente de una cinta negra: los freires la llevan tambien; pero deben tener la misma cruz de lienzo blanco sobre el manteo ó vestido al lado izquierdo, cuya distincion usan igualmente los caballeros profesos; y los sirvientes la llevan de tres solos brazos, de esmalte ó de lienzo, segun su estado.

La cosa va quedando clara. Se ve que los hermanos sirvientes no podían llevar el emblema de la cruz al completo en su uniforme, y para distinguirse de otros hermanos de mayor rango eliminaban el brazo derecho de la cruz, y a este emblema se denominaba *martillo*, entiendo que por la semejanza de la divisa resultante con la forma de este. Imagino que eliminar el "brazo derecho" será por aquello de ser el brazo diestro, en alusión a que estos hermanos sirvientes no eran tan útiles como los caballeros y los religiosos.